# Sumar valores a una variable de forma consecutiva [C# /Unity]

Tags: c#, array, bucle-for, unity, unity2d

Necesito asignar a una variable el valor de otras variables, pero que no sea la suma de todo, sino los valores de forma consecutiva. La verdad es que no se muy bien como explicar lo que quiero hacer, así que mejor pongo un ejemplo:

Tengo un array:

```
int[] arrayCount = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Mediante un `for{}` le asigno el valor que quiero a cada variable y queda así:

```
arrayCount[0] = 0;
arrayCount[0] = 1;
arrayCount[0] = 2;
arrayCount[0] = 3;
```

Creo otra variable. Por ejemplo:

```
int arrayValores;
```

Ahora quiero que la variable que acabo de crear tenga los valores del array, pero en lugar de ser una suma, quede así:

```
arrayValores = 0123;
```

**¿Como podría hacer esto?** Seguramente la pregunta sea muy noob, pero estoy empezando a aprender Unity y C# (y programación en general xD)

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, no puedes pasar un array de enteros a un entero en sí mismo. El array, continuará siendo un array durante toda la ejecución. Sin embargo, para lograr lo que comentas, debes recorrer cada uno de los valores del array y concatenarlo en un String:

```
int[] arrayCount = { 1, 3, 0, 5 };
String numsConcatenated = "";
for (int i = 0; i < arrayCount.Length; i++) {
    numsConcatenated += arrayCount[i].ToString();
}
```

Mediante la ejecución de este ejemplo se obtendrá:

```
numsConcatenated = "1305";
```

Y sí, realmente necesitases pasarlo a int, sólo tendrías que transformarlo:

```
int numsConcateanedInt = Int32.ParseInt(numsConcatenated);
```

Espero resuelva tu duda.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! ahora mismo lo implemento en mi codigo me has ayudado un monto

Comment: Ánimo, lo sacarás :-)

Comment: Por favor, si @Grommy ha solucionado tu pregunta, márcala como correcta/contestada. Ayudarás a la comunidad con ese simple gesto. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Totalmente de acuerdo con la respuesta, yo simplemente voy a hacer un avance en este tema con respecto a usar listas en lugar de arrays, en el caso de que quieras tener más control sobre su manejo, ya sea quitando, agregando o controlando los valores del array con mayor flexibilidad.

Un ejemplo claro con lo que preguntas sería el siguiente:

```
List<int> listCount = new List<int>();

    string lista = "";

    Console.WriteLine("Introduces el numero de datos que tendrá la lista");
    int numeroDeLista = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < numeroDeLista; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Introduces el valor de cada dato de la lista de datos");
        listCount.Add(Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }

    foreach (int list in listCount)
    {
        lista += list.ToString();
    }

    int listaInt = Int32.Parse(lista);

    Console.WriteLine(listaInt);

    //

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Por un lado el foreach es otra manera de recorrer listas ahorrando código, y simplemente funciona pasando el valor de la lista con una variable que lo recoja, y recorriendo la lista con la palabra clave in. EJ: (int valor in listaValores).

Como puedes ver el tipo de valor de la lista se especifica dentro de las llaves angulares <>, puesto que es un tipo de objeto genérico, cosa que no hace falta que entiendas para usarlo, puesto que la única diferencia es que en lugar de especificar el tipo antes como en los arrays (int[]), lo especificas dentro de las llaves angulares (list), el resto es igual solo que como has podido ver en el ejemplo, te da mucha más flexibilidad que un array.

El ejemplo quedaría así al ejecutarlo:

[image: Ejemplo Práctico de listas]